# Schrödinger equation for charged particle in potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, operators, momentum, wavefunction

This might be a silly question, but I don't think it is trivial.
I am trying to solve an example for my class. In it the Schrödinger equation for a charged particle in a vector potential is given:
$$i\hbar \dot\psi=(\frac{1}{2m}(\hat{\vec{p}}-\frac{e}{c}\vec{A})^2+e\phi)\psi$$
When expanding the first term one gets: $$\hat{\vec{p}}^2-\hat{\vec{p}}\vec{A}-\vec{A}\hat{\vec{p}}+\vec{A}^2.$$ Does the momentum operator act in the second term on the product of the magnetic vector potential with the wave function or just the vector potential?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it acts on the $A_x$: 
$$
(-i\hbar \partial_x A_x) \psi= ( -i\hbar A_x\partial_x) \psi+ (-i\hbar \psi \partial_x) A
$$

Comment: so the result would be: $(\hat{\vec{p}}^2-\hat{\vec{p}}\vec{A}-\vec{A}\hat{\vec{p}}+\vec{A}^2) \psi = \hat{\vec{p}}^2\psi-\hat{\vec{p}}(\vec{A}\psi)-\vec{A}\hat{\vec{p}}(\psi)+\vec{A}^2\psi= \hat{\vec{p}}^2\psi-\hat{\vec{p}}(\vec{A})\psi)-2\vec{A}\hat{\vec{p}}(\psi)+\vec{A}^2\psi$?

Comment: Yes --- except that  the term where ${\bf p}$ acts on ${\bf A}$ should read $-({\bf P}\cdot {\bf A})\psi$, i.e there is a scalar product. If  you use the gauge in which $\nabla \cdot {\bf A}=0$ then this term vanishes, which makes a popular gauge choice.